# @JsonIdentityInfo Causes Undesired Results

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, jackson, relationship

I use hibernate orm to map have a many-to-many relationship between `Role` and `Privilege` like so:

`Role`

```
@Entity
@Audited
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "roleId")
public class Role extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false) 
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private Integer roleId;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roleCollection")
    private Collection<Privilege> privilegeCollection;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roleCollection")
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "privilege_privilege_id IN (SELECT ph.parent_privilege FROM privilege_hierachy ph)")
    private Collection<Privilege> parentPrivilegeCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "roleId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<User> userCollection;

    public Role() {
    }
    //Getters and Setters removed for brevity
}
```

`Privilege`

```
@Entity
@Audited
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "privilegeId")
public class Privilege extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "privilege_id")
    private Integer privilegeId;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Size(max = 150)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "friendly_name")
    private String friendlyName;

    @JoinTable(name = "role_privilege", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "privilege_id")},  inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "role_role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id")})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Role> roleCollection;

    @JoinTable(name = "privilege_hierachy", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_privilege", referencedColumnName = "privilege_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "child_privilege", referencedColumnName = "privilege_id")})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Privilege> privilegeCollection;

    public Privilege() {
    }
    // Getter and Setters removed for brevity
}
```

What i want to get is all `Role`s with their respective `Privilege`s in JSON. Obviously that brings back `StackOverflowError` as you can see `Role`
 goes to `Privilege` which goes back to `Role` and so on.

Because is many-to-many bidirectional i annotated it with `@JsonIdentityInfo` both sides of the relation.

The desired result is to get roles with privileges without cyclic stackoverflowerror, but what is get as result is Json below. What i dont understand is items in `privilegeCollection` some are objects which is fine but why numbers (57,97,165,161,124)... where are those comming from...why not objects

[image]

Comment: have you solved it?